# Linked List implementation in C++

Tags: c++, linked-list, iterator

I've three header(.hpp) files that define a node, a singly linked list and an iterator. This should together build my singly linked-list.
Here's the node.

```
#ifndef NODE_HPP
#define NODE_HPP

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template <typename T> struct node {


public:
    explicit node(const T& value, node* next = 0): value_(value), next_(next){}


private:
    T value_;
    node* next_;

};

#endif //NODE_HPP
```

Here's my slist

```
#ifndef SLIST_HPP
#define SLIST_HPP

#include "node.hpp"
#include "iterator.hpp"

template <typename T> class slist{

public:
    class iterator;

    slist() :head_(0){ }

    bool empty() const{return (head_==0);}

    int size() const{
        int s=0;
        iterator last=end();
        for(iterator i= begin(); i!= last; ++i; ++s);
        return s;
    };

    iterator begin() { return iterator(head_); }
    iterator end() { return iterator(0); }

    void insert(iterator p, const T& t);

    void erase(iterator p){
        node<T>* tmp = p.node_->next_;
        p.node_->value = p.node_->next_.value;
        p.node_->next_=p.node_->next_->next_;

        delete tmp;
        return p;
    };

private:
    node<T>* head_;

};

#endif //SLIST_HPP
```

And here's my iterator class

```
#ifndef ITERATOR_HPP
#define ITERATOR_HPP

#include "slist.hpp"
#include "node.hpp"



class iterator{

public:
    explicit iterator(node<T>* node=0) :node_(node){ }

    T& operator* (){return node_-> value_;}
    T* operator->(){return node_->value_;}

    iterator& operator++(){
        if(node_ != 0) node_ = node_->next_;
        return *this;
    }

    iterator operator++(int){
        iterator tmp = *this;
        if(node_!= 0) node_ = node_->next_;
        return tmp;
    }

    bool operator==(const iterator& iter) const { return (node_ == iter.node_); }

    bool operator!=(const iterator& iter) const { return (node_ != iter.node_); }


private:
    node<T>* node_;
};

#endif //ITERATOR_HPP
```

The problem is nothing seems to get resolved. The code doesn't compile because the slist can't read into values from the iterator despite iterator being defined inside slist. Even the iterator class itself displays squiggly on methods that return an iterator object. Can someone help me understand what's going wrong here.

Comment: Why the down vote even without a comment(reason)?

Comment: You seem to have forgotten the `template ...` line in `iterator.hpp`. Are you sure this is the real code?

Comment: @Jumper _"Why the down vote even without a comment(reason)?"_ There are rarely downvotes without reason: _"Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: **[How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**."_ Concentrate on the _minimal_.

Comment: What do you mean by unreal code. Even if I template the iterator class, I'm still getting the same errors.

Comment: [facepalm] You have to start from the simple and work up to the complex. Does your node template compile? Yes? Good. Test it. Does it work? Yes? Good. Does your iterator template compile? And so on. Don't attempt slist until iterator works perfectly.

Comment: Node does compile, but iterator doesn't. Thats part of my question.

Answer (score 0):

If your compiler doesn't tell you where the problems are, start simple and build up. What's the simplest `iterator` you can think of? Try this:

```
template <typename T>
class iterator{
};
```

So far, so good. Now add complexity a little at a time, testing at every step. You can write `slist` now, or add functionality to `iterator`. You'll notice a problem as soon as you write something like

```
for(iterator i= begin(); i!= last; ++i; ++s);
```

When you hit a snag like that, don't add any more complexity until you fix it.